# Is there a pretty syntax for complex comparison?

Tags: ruby, comparison-operators

The `<=>` method should return `-1`, `0` or `1` for "less than", "equal to", and "greater than", respectively. For some types of sortable objects, it is normal to base the sort order on multiple properties. The following works, but I think it looks clumsy:

```
class LeagueStats
  attr_accessor :points, :goal_diff
  def initialize pts, gd
    @points = pts
    @goal_diff = gd
  end
  def <=> other
    compare_pts = points <=> other.points
    return compare_pts unless compare_pts == 0
    goal_diff <=> other.goal_diff
  end
end
```

Trying it:

```
[
  LeagueStats.new( 10, 7 ),
  LeagueStats.new( 10, 5 ),
  LeagueStats.new( 9, 6 )
].sort
# => [
#      #<LS @points=9, @goal_diff=6>,
#      #<LS @points=10, @goal_diff=5>,
#      #<LS @points=10, @goal_diff=7>
#    ]
```

Perl treats `0` as a false value, which allows complex comparisons with different syntax:

```
{ 
  return ( $self->points <=> $other->points ) ||
         ( $self->goal_diff <=> $other->goal_diff ); 
}
```

I find the fall-through on `0` via the `||` operator simple to read and elegant. One thing I like about using `||` is the short-circuiting of calculations once the comparison has a value.

I cannot find anything similar in Ruby. Are there any nicer ways to build the same complex of comparisons (or anything else picking the first non-zero item), ideally without needing to calculate all values in advance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to sawa's answer, the result <del>can also</del> should be evaluated in-place, in order to return -1, 0 or +1:

```
class LeagueStats
  def <=> other
    [points, goal_diff] <=> [other.points, other.goal_diff]
  end
end
```

This works because of [`Array#<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E):

> Arrays are compared in an “element-wise” manner; the first two
>   elements that are not equal will determine the return value for the
>   whole comparison.

After implementing `<=>`, you can include [`Comparable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Comparable.html) and get `<`, `<=`, `==`, `>=`, `>` and `between?` for free.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) instead of `sort`:

```
[LeagueStats.new(10,7),LeagueStats.new(10,5),LeagueStats.new(9,6)].sort_by { |ls|
  [ls.points, ls.goal_diff]
}
# => [#<LeagueStats:0x00000001a806c8 @points=9, @goal_diff=6>,
#     #<LeagueStats:0x00000001a806f0 @points=10, @goal_diff=5>,
#     #<LeagueStats:0x00000001a80718 @points=10, @goal_diff=7>]
```

---

```
class LeagueStats
  ...

  def to_a
    [points, goal_diff]
  end

  def <=> other
    to_a <=> other.to_a
  end
end
```

Comment: That's cool, but I'd like LeagueStats to have an inherent sort order, it is what they are for.

Comment: @NeilSlater, Okay, I added another code that derived from sawa's answer.